# whats is the problem on this code? need help to resolve django search error

Tags: python, django, search

Here is the views.py

```py
#search
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get["query"]
    if len(query)>78:
        allItem = Item.object.none()
    else:
        allItemTitle = Item.object.filter(title__icontains=query)
        allItemDescription = Item.object.filter(description__icontains=query)
        allItem = allItem.Title.union(allItemDescription)

    if allItem.count() == 0:
        messages.warning(request, "No result found")
    params = {'allItem': allItem, 'query':query}
    return render(request, 'home/search.html', params)
    #search
```

Here is the url.py

```py
 path('search/', views.Search, name='search'),
```

and finally HTML Source code is here

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<div class="breadcrumb-area section-padding-1 bg-gray breadcrumb-ptb-2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="breadcrumb-content text-center">
            <div class="breadcrumb-title">
                <h2>Shop 3 Column</h2>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home 01 </a>
                </li>
                <li><span> &gt; </span></li>
                <li class="active"> shop </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="shop-area pt-70 pb-100">
    <div class="container">

<div class="container">
    <h3>Search Results</h3>
    {% if allItem|length < 1 %}
    <p>No Search result found</p>
did not match any document    Your search query:<b>{{query}}</b>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in object_list %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <div class="product-wrap mb-50">
                <div class="product-img default-overlay mb-25">
                    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">
                        <img class="default-img" src="{{ item.image }}" height="463" width="370"alt="">
                        <span class="badge-black badge-right-0 badge-top-0 badge-width-height-1">{{ item.label }}</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product-action product-action-position-1">
                <a title="Add to Cart" href="{{ item.link }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Shop Now</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content-2 title-font-width-400 text-center">
                    <h3><a href=""></a>{{ item.title }}</a></h3>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        {% if item.old_price %}
                        <span class="new-price"><b>$ {{ item.price }}</b></span>
                        <span class="old-price" style="color: red;">$ {{ item.old_price }} </span>   
                        {% else %}   
                        <span class="new-price"><b>$ {{ item.price }}</b></span>
                        {% endif %}  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



{% include 'footer.html' %}    
{% endblock %}
```

```html
 <!---search-->
                    <div class="search-content-2 search-content-2-mrg">
                        <form class="search-form" action="{% url 'roserga:search' %}">
                            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search">
                            <button class="button-search" type="submit"><i class="dlicon ui-1_zoom"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---search end-->
```

many times tried to resolve, but no luck, the query did not take in body tag and not showing results.

Comment: You should provide the traceback or at least some description of the error. Anyway, this `query = request.GET.get["query"]` is not right. It should be `query = request.GET.get("query")`. Also this line `allItem = allItem.Title.union(allItemDescription)` should return NameError, since `allItem` is undefined.

Comment: In HTML you refer to `object_list` which isn't in the context. Where did you copy paste this code from?

Comment: for home list view, the same as search result  view

Answer (score 0):

In you urls.py:

```
 path('search/', views.Search, name='search'),
```

You call **views.Search** (capital "S") I think it's **views.search** (lowercase "s") because it's your name function in views.py